# Timers on group chats in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a group chat app in Swift 2. I want to set a 48 hour (or any other duration) timer for people to respond/contribute to the group conversation. If they don't they're out of the group chat. How do I do this?

I'm using the latest version of Xcode, and as mentioned above, I'm programming in Swift 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can set background "timers" in your iOS app using `UILocalNotification`, but I've put timers in quotes because all it would do is show an alert on your user's screen after 48 hours have passed – it wouldn't actually boot them from the group chat.

The solution, then, is a server problem: however you are exchanging data between clients needs to be able to say, "sorry, you've been away too long" when the user tries to return.

The exception is if you're exchanging the messages using iCloud, then yes this would be app code: you'd need to query your public database to fetch the latest date the user contributed, and block them on the device from contributing further.